# unable to select from a second drop down list

Tags: ruby, rubygems, drop-down-menu, watir

Using Rubygems and Watir

I'm unable to select options from a second drop down.
here is the code of the 2 drop downs

```
<select class="LocalUtility" name="Accounts[0][Local_Utility]" id="">
<select class="LocalUtility" name="Accounts[1][Local_Utility]" id="">
```

I'm able to select options from the 1st by using

```
browser.select_list(:class, 'LocalUtility').set ('value')
```

I tried to use index for the 2nd drop down (tried with 1,2)

```
browser.select_list(:index, 1).set ('value')
```

And I cannot use the name because Ruby is throwing errors due to what I'm suspecting is that Ruby does not like the brackets [1][Local_Utility]

```
browser.select_list(:name 'Accounts[1][Local_Utility]').set ('value')
```

Is there a possible solution to this?

Comment: and I just noticed that you have no separator in your :name example above.

Comment: Yep, the square brackets inside a string should not be a problem.  The lack of either a comma or => seperating your :how and 'what' on the other hand would cause an error if you used that exact command in your scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
browser.select_list(:class => "LocalUtility", :index => 1).select("value")
```

to set the value in the second select list.

I'm surprised that the name doesn't work though.  There's a potential typo in what you've supplied us with

Try

```
browser.select_list(:name => "Accounts[1][Local_Utility]").select("value")
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using a regex match?

```
browser.select_list(:class => 'LocalUtility', :name => /1/).set 'value'
```

Please forgive me if my syntax is not right because I have been using watir-webdriver lately (and your web page code is insufficient to recreate the problem).